# Add one extra slash to url path

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi my URL is like http://example.net/hi-how-are-you.
I want to convert this URL as http://example.net//hi-how-are-you that is converting by last single slash sign with double slash sign.

I want my last slash of URL with double slash with java script / J query.

http://example.net/hi-how-are-you

http://example.net//hi-how-are-you

Comment: Add your code here

Comment: use `split` functionality in js

Comment: For what reason would you want to do that? Other than to confuse your visitors and kill your SEO.

Comment: referring to [MDN URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) you may write: **var x = new URL('http://example.net/hi-how-are-you');var result = x.origin + '/' + x.pathname;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to do that, but following code will work for you.

```js
var url = 'http://example.net/hi-how-are-you';
var pos = url.lastIndexOf('/');
url = url.substring(0,pos)+'//'+url.substring(pos+1);
console.log(url);
```